# select array by matching its property value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

```
var array = [
{'a':1,'b':2},
{'a':1,'b':3},
{'a':1,'b':0},
]
```

I want to return array that its' property b is equal to 2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) like this

```
var result = array.filter(function(currentObject) {
    return currentObject.b === 2;
});

console.log(result);
# [ { a: 1, b: 2 } ]
```

You can also do this with plain for loop, like this

```
var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
    if (array[i].b === 2) {
        result.push(array[i]);
    }
}

console.log(result);
# [ { a: 1, b: 2 } ]
```

Comment: how can I use that 'return'?

Comment: @user3522457 `filter` will gather all the items for which the function returns `true` and all those items will be available in `result`, like I have shown in my example.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result;
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {

     if (array[i].b === 2) {
         result = array[i];
         break;
     }

}

console.log(result);
```

use a `break` to make some difference.